# 180 degree video player not working as expected using videojs-panorama

Tags: video.js

I was trying 180 degree video player provided by videojs-panorama.

I referred the following code snipet.

```
var player = window.player = videojs('videojs-panorama-player', {
        autoplay: true
    });

    player.panorama({
        videoType: "VR1803D",
        clickToToggle: true,
        autoMobileOrientation: true,
        VREnable: true,
        Notice: {
            Enable: true,
            Message: (isMobile())? "please drag and drop the video" : "please use your mouse drag and drop the video"
        }
    });

    window.player = player;
```

Used this version of videojs-panorama.

https://github.com/yanwsh/videojs-panorama/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta

But the video appears to be cut from left-right/top-bottom.

Here is the screenshot.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppnED.jpg "180 degree player"

The same video when checked on youtube, plays properly.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oeln0dsNzsY

Let me know, what am I missing here?